# How to force rerendeing after updating tab by ajax call in ExtJs 5.0?

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs, tabs, extjs5

I have main page with a tab control:

```
Ext.define("Test.index.TabsController", {
    extend: "Ext.app.ViewController",
    alias: "controller.tabs-controller",
    onTabChange: function (panel, newItem, oldItem) {
        if (!newItem.html && newItem.loader) {
            newItem.loader.load();
        }
    }
});

Ext.define("Test.index.Tabs", {
    extend: "Ext.tab.Panel",
    controller: "tabs-controller",
    listeners: { tabchange: "onTabChange" },
    items: [
        {
            title: "Static Tab",
            html: "This is static tab",
        }, {
            title: "Ajax Tab",
            loader: {
                loadMask: true,
                removeAll: true,
                url: 'views/ajax.html',
                contentType: "html",
                scripts: true,
                renderer: function (loader, response, request) {
                    loader.getTarget().update(response.responseText, request.scripts === true);
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    ]
});

Ext.create("Test.index.Tabs", {
    renderTo: Ext.get("tabs")
});

<div id="tabs"></div>
```

And a separate resource (I tried both static html file and ASP.MET MVC partial view) containing a grid populated from external rest (ASP.NET Web API) web service:

```
Ext.define("Test.models.Test", {
    extend: "Ext.data.Model",
    fields: ["name", "updateDate"]
});

var userStore = Ext.create("Ext.data.Store", {
    model: "Test.models.Test",
    autoLoad: true,
    autoSync: true,
    proxy: {
        type: "rest",
        url: "http://localhost/api/test",
        reader: {
            type: "json"
        }
    },
});

Ext.create("Ext.grid.Panel", {
    renderTo: Ext.get("container"),
    store: userStore,
    columns: [
        {
            text: "ID", dataIndex: "id"
        }, {
            text: "Name", dataIndex: "name"
        }
    ]
});

<div id="container"></div>
```

It works but not properly:

- when I select second tab nothing happens
- I select first tab back
- then select second tab again, now grid is visible

How can I force rerendering right after update?

Comment: did you try component.updateLayout?

Comment: @Luiguis: No luck. At least where I tried it. Not sure I did it right. Where and when should I call it, do you know? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Luiguis, I found where to call `updateLayout()`:

```
renderer: function (loader, response, request) {
    var callback = function () {
        loader.getTarget().updateLayout();
    };
    loader.getTarget().update(response.responseText,
                              request.scripts === true,
                              callback);
    return true;
}
```